# GORM Trigger pattern in Grails 2.5.4

Tags: grails, triggers, grails-orm

I want to implement the concept of `Trigger` objects in Grails for my domain classes. Grails allows me to define methods like `beforeInsert()` in my domain classes to [handle insert, update and delete events](http://docs.grails.org/2.5.4/guide/GORM.html#advancedGORMFeatures), similar to how SQL databases have the concept of database triggers. But to separate concerns I'd like to move all of the trigger logic outside of the domain class.

Ideally I can simply define a `static` list of trigger classes in my domain class and then iterate through those in the `beforeInsert()` method. Sample code shown below.

```
static beforeInsertTriggers = [AccountNameTrigger, AccountDumpTrigger]

def beforeInsert() {
    for (Class<Trigger> triggerClass : beforeInsertTriggers) {
        triggerClass.newInstance().using(this).execute()
    }
}
```

I've created a [sample Grails 2.5.4 project on GitHub](https://github.com/martyychang/grails-domain-trigger-demo/tree/master) illustrating what I'm trying to do. But **the problem** is that the triggers literally are standalone islands of logic without the ability to autowire services. How can I better set up this `Trigger` pattern or something similar? So I may autowire services and other beans into the `Trigger` instances?

I am also trying to keep the design simple and readable.

- Avoid cluttering the domain class with fields and properties that are not related to the data model. To me this means no autowired beans in the domain class.
- Define the list of triggers using the trigger class names (or bean names, if need be). This may be overly idealistic, but hey...

For what it's worth, part of my inspiration also comes from how [Salesforce implements triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_syntax.htm) as distinct units of self-contained code.

Answer (score 0):

Register your Triggers as Singleton Beans and there you can inject other services/beans. You can create your custom beans via resources.groovy.

Lets take the example of AccountDumpTrigger. Lets make a simple change to it:

```
package grails.domain.trigger.demo.triggers

import grails.domain.trigger.demo.Account
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplication

/**
 * Created by marty on 6/25/16.
 */
class AccountDumpTrigger extends AbstractTrigger<Account> {

    GrailsApplication grailsApplication

    @Override
    void execute() {
        println grailsApplication.isInitialised()
        println resource.dump()
    }
}
```

And code in resources.groovy or in your plugin's doWithSpring closure:

```
accountDumpTrigger(grails.domain.trigger.demo.triggers.AccountDumpTrigger) { bean ->
    bean.factoryMethod = 'getInstance'
    /*
     either refer each bean individually  or you can use:
     bean.autowire = "byType"
       OR
     bean.autowire = "byName"
    */
    grailsApplication = ref("grailsApplication")
}
```

And inside your domain:

```
static beforeInsertTriggers = [AccountDumpTrigger]

def beforeInsert() {
    for (Class<Trigger> triggerClass : beforeInsertTriggers) {
        triggerClass.instance.using(this).execute()
    }
}
```

And instead of writing your code inside `beforeInsert` you can also do the same by registering an implementation of `AbstractPersistenceEventListener`. This way you don't have to repeat your code. Also yo can move it to a parent class.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and detailed response. Do I need to manually wire every bean using the `ref()` syntax in *resources.groovy*? And I will look into the event listener option as well since that is new to me.

Comment: Yes if you are creating Trigger classes inside src/groovy. If you will make your Triggers as a Service then you don't have to do that. Making them a Service would give you the added advantage of Hibernate Session and Transaction management.

Comment: Why wouldn't autoWire work for this?  putting bean.autowire = 'byName' in your Trigger declaration in resources.groovy should get you injection of variables if the names match.

Comment: @billjamesdev Sorry my bad. Updated my answer. It may be the case that we don't declare the bean variable in the code with same name or type(happens a lot with me ;-)). That's why I always prefer manual injection.

Comment: @SandeepPoonia related question for you about where to put the event listener subclasses: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043214/where-to-put-abstractpersistenceeventlistener-subclasses-in-grails-2-5-4

Comment: @SandeepPoonia the modified code you wrote for getting a new instance of the trigger in `beforeInsert()` seems to reference a non-existent property. `No such property: instance for class: grails.domain.trigger.demo.triggers.LeadNameTrigger.`

Comment: Please check if you have applied `Singleton` annotation to `LeadNameTrigger`.