# Where to put AbstractPersistenceEventListener subclasses in Grails 2.5.4?

Tags: grails, conventions

I want to subclass `AbstractPersistenceEventListener` so I can [register custom event listeners in Grails 2.5.4](http://docs.grails.org/2.5.4/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping). However, where should I place these subclasses?

Most importantly I want these event listeners to use autowired beans, especially service beans. If I put these classes in **src/groovy**, it seems I'll have to manually register the beans in **resources.groovy**, which is an extra step I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913877/custom-event-listener-example-in-grails-documentation) shows how you can register a custom event listener in grails if you are not doing it using a plugin where you can register it inside `doWithApplicationContext` closure instead of doing it inside `Bootstrap.groovy`.

And you should put these classes under src/groovy. And no, you don't need to register the listener as a bean or any other beans again inside `resources.groovy`. However if your listener need to use any bean then you can declare a field for that and initialize it when you are registering the listener. For eg if you need to inject `grailsApplication` bean in your listener then do this while registering your listener:

```
def grailsApplication

def init = { servletContext ->
    def applicationContext = servletContext.getAttribute(ApplicationAttributes.APPLICATION_CONTEXT)
    applicationContext.eventTriggeringInterceptor.datastores.each { k, datastore ->
    GormEventListener listener = new GormEventListener(datastore)
    listener.with{
        application = grailsApplication
    }
    applicationContext.addApplicationListener(listener)
}
```